# Delphi Win64: memory is growing without leaks when using TThread.Synchronize()

Tags: delphi, memory

I am facing an issue within the life application that memory (shown in Task Manager, or in `GetProcessMemoryInfo -> PagefileUsage`) is constantly growing while there is no any leaks reported by FastMM4.

Trying to narrow the issue, I did my best to create the smallest possible test case, but it still came out too big.

However, I am still posting it here because it's the only way I found to show the issue.

So, what this test does:

1. Checks occupied memory on startup reported by `GetMemoryManagerState()` and by `GetProcessMemoryInfo()`.
2. Creates 10k threads, which allocate some memory.
3. After all 10k threads are terminated, all allocated memory is freed.

I double checked many times with Eurekalog and FastMM in full debug mode that all created objects do not leak.

4. Until the Stop button is hit, the process continues to Step 2.

So, despite that I'm sure that all objects are being released, occupied memory after the first run has increased dramatically by almost 170MB.

**Update 1:**

Finally I found out (thanks @Remy) that the issue in this test case was caused by memory fragmentation.

In this particular case fragmentation came from the `System.SysUtils.EventCache`

Adding this code to the beginning completely eliminates the effect of growing used memory:

```
for i := Low(WCache) to High(WCache) do
  WCache[i] := MonitorSupport.NewWaitObject;
for i := Low(WCache) to High(WCache) do
  MonitorSupport.FreeWaitObject(WCache[i]);
```

However for the life application this does nothing, cause there are probably more other fragmentation sources.

So my new question: Is there any tools and techniques to optimize memory fragmentaion?
All that I found is `FastMM4 FastMM_LogStateToFile`
It shows `Overhead` and `Efficiency` value which as I understand means how bad is memory fragmentaion, however it doesn't give a tool to find a reason?

---

Below is the original test case.

Application log looks like this:

```
Before: Mem: Used 67 kb  UsedOS: 4 MB    
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 170 MB   
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 178 MB    
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 181 MB     
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 176 MB   
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 182 MB   
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 178 MB   
After:  Mem: Used 323 kb  UsedOS: 206 MB
```

The code:

```pascal
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults,
  Math, psAPI, REST.Client,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
  ThreadsCount = 10000;

type
  TForm12 = class(TForm)
    MemLabel: TLabel;
    MemTimer: TTimer;
    bStart: TButton;
    bStop: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure MemTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure bStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure bStopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure UpdateMemInfo;
  public
    procedure LogNextStep;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TOrder = packed record
    sx:            string[10];
    Time:          TDateTime;
    x,y,z:         double;
  end;

  POrder = ^TOrder;

  TTestThread = class(TThread)
    WaitFlag:  boolean;
    public
      Num:    integer;
      ptr:    POrder;
      R:      TRestRequest;
      Name:   string;
      data:   array [1..50] of double;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form12: TForm12;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

var
  GlobalUsedMem, GlobalUsedOSMem, AddedCount:          integer; // MB
  ThCount, ThGlobalID:                                 integer;
  JobDone, TestStopRequest:                            boolean;
  ThList:                                              TList<TTestThread>;
  OrderList:                                           TList<POrder>;


procedure CreateNewThread;
begin
  TTestThread.Create(false);
end;

procedure CreateNewTest;
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      k:         integer;
    begin
      sleep(3000);
      for k := 1 to ThreadsCount do
        CreateNewThread;
    end).Start;
end;

procedure CLeanOrders;
var
  o: POrder;
begin
  for o in OrderList do FreeMem(o);
  OrderList.CLear;
end;

procedure TForm12.bStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateMemInfo;
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Before: ' + MemLabel.Caption);
  ThGlobalID := 0;
  TestStopRequest := false;
  JobDone := false;
  AddedCount := 0;

  CreateNewTest;
end;


procedure TForm12.bStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestStopRequest := true;
end;

procedure TForm12.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  TestStopRequest := true;
  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    sleep(10);
  until JobDOne;
  ThList.Free;
  OrderList.Free;

end;

procedure TForm12.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  JobDone := true;
  ThList := TList<TTestThread>.Create;
  OrderList := TList<POrder>.Create;

end;

procedure TForm12.LogNextStep;
begin
  UpdateMemInfo;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('After: ' + MemLabel.Caption);
end;

procedure TForm12.UpdateMemInfo;
var
  m4:             UInt64;
  mx:             integer;
  st:             TMemoryManagerState;
  sb:             TSmallBlockTypeState;
  MemCounters:    TProcessMemoryCounters;

begin
  MemCounters.cb := SizeOf(MemCounters);
  if GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @MemCounters, SizeOf(MemCounters))
    then GlobalUsedOSMem := round(MemCounters.PagefileUsage / 1000000);;

  GetMemoryManagerState(st);
  m4 :=  st.TotalAllocatedMediumBlockSize + st.TotalAllocatedLargeBlockSize;
  for sb in st.SmallBlockTypeStates do begin
    m4 := m4 + sb.UseableBlockSize * sb.AllocatedBlockCount;
  end;
  GlobalUsedMem := round(m4 / 1000);

  MemLabel.Caption := Format(' Mem: Used %d kb  UsedOS: %d MB   O: %d  Th: %d ',
   [ GlobalUsedMem, GlobalUsedOSMem, OrderList.Count, ThCount  ]);

end;

procedure TForm12.MemTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateMemInfo;
end;


procedure SyncProc(o: TTestThread);
begin
  OrderList.Add(o.ptr);
  o.R := TRestRequest.Create(nil);
  o.Name := 'Test Thread ' + o.Num.toString;

  ThList.Add(o);
  inc(AddedCount);
end;

procedure SyncDel(o: TTestThread);
var
  k:  integer;
  s:  string;
begin
  dec(AddedCount);
  ThList.remove(o);
  FreeAndNil(o.R);

  If AddedCount = 0 then begin

    ThGlobalID := 0;
    thList.Clear;
    CLeanOrders;
    Form12.LogNextStep;

    If not TestStopRequest then
      CreateNewTest;
  end;

  If (not TestStopRequest) and (random(5) = 1) and (ThCount > 1000) then CreateNewThread;
end;

{ TTestThread }

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
var
  k:           integer;
  pLarge, pSmall, pMed:  pointer;
  tm1:   Uint64;
  workingTime: integer;

const
  IterCount = 50;

begin
  WaitFlag := false;
  AtomicIncrement(ThCount);

  Num := AtomicIncrement(ThGlobalID) - 1;

  sleep(random(500));

  GetMem(pLarge, 100500);
  GetMem(pMed, 25000);
  GetMem(pSmall, 800);
  FreeMem(pLarge);
  New(ptr);
  ptr.Time := Now;

  Synchronize( procedure begin SyncProc(self); end );

  FreeMem(pMed);
  FreeMem(pSmall);
  workingTime := 3000 + random (2000);
  tm1 := GetTickCount64;

  repeat

    Sleep(100);

  until TestStopRequest or (abs(GetTickCount64 - tm1) > workingTime);

  sleep(random(1000));

  k := AtomicDecrement(ThCount);
  JobDone := (k=0);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;

  Synchronize( procedure begin SyncDel(self); end );

end;

end.
```

Comment: don't spawn 10k threads, use a threadpool.

Comment: Are you taking into account that Delphi's MM does not return freed memory back to the OS, but rather caches it for later reuse? If you fragment memory (which FastMM is supposed to avoid, at least for small/medium allocations), then the MM may not be able to reuse cached memory, thus going back to the OS for more and more memory.

Comment: In any case, I see that your `TThread` objects will not be freed correctly if they raise exceptions (you should move `FreeOnTerminate:=True` into the thread constructor instead). And various other allocations should be protected with `try..finally` blocks to account for exceptions, as well. Also, you should be using `Dispose()` instead of `FreeMem()` when clearing your `OrderList`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau many thanks, you are right about fragmentation, could you please look to Update in my post?